# Non-empty directories but I'm unable to see any file in it

Tags: windows-10

I'm in the process of cleaning my music collection, using MusicBrainz Picard to automatically move and rename them. I then look for empty folders so I can delete them, using xplorer2 (file manager).

While doing this I've encountered *a lot* of directories that are not empty, according to both xplorer2 and the Windows file explorer, although I cannot see anything in them. They usually contain one or two small files, typically around 20-70kB, but sometimes a bit higher (300kB). This is what the folder properties window says anyway:

[image]

However, when I visit those folders, I don't see anything in them.
**Of course I've set both xplorer2 and Windows Explorer to show hidden files.**

When using the command line to get information on those folders, it says that they contain two subfolders (if I'm reading correctly), but it doesn't list them.

[image]

What am I missing here? Where does this non-zero size come from? How can I see what it is?

Comment: if you `rd /s "1974-Tangerine Dream - Phaedra"` does command prompt complain that the folder isn't empty?

Comment: @spikey_richie no, it just asks for confirmation. I said Y and the folder has been deleted (I made a backup first).

Comment: OK, chuck in a `/Q` as well, and you will suppress the prompt.

Comment: That's not the issue though. I have no problem deleting those folders (in explorer or in command line). I want to know why they're considered non-empty and what is actually in them that I cannot see.

Comment: To see all files in console use `dir /ahs`

Comment: @Robert thanks. It indeed shows two files, AlbumArtSmall.jpg and Folder.jpg. But why aren't those files visible when I view the folder in Explorer (or xplorer2)? Like I said, I made sure that the option "show hidden files, folders and drives" is checked.

Comment: Those files are not visible in the Explorer because by default the option to show hidden and option to show system files is disabled (see explorer options).

Comment: @Robert Aaah, OK, they're considered _system files_, not just hidden files. I thought the "show hidden files" option would be enough. I forgot there was another, distinct option. That answers my question then. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

So it turns out those hidden files were not "just" hidden files, but also *system* files.

System files will remain hidden even though the *"show hidden files, folders and drives"* option is checked in the Explorer options. You also have to uncheck the *"Hide protected system files (Recommended)"* for those files to become visible. This wasn't clear to me.

Thanks to @Robert in the comments for pointing that out.